# Views shows the page for deleted nodes, instead of the 404 error page

Tags: views

I am running Drupal 7, and have created several views. I am noticing a problem: If one adds a node ID in the URL, it returns the views page for that content type instead of 404 error.

I want that when someone enter http://www.muktware.com/articles/3583, Drupal returns the 404 error page.